# Android getSupportedQualities returns wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

When I use QualitySelector.getSupportedQualities(cameraInfo) on a Samsumg Core A03 it returns:

FHD
HD
SD

But this device only supports SD.
What makes the application crash, unless I put SD manually, but it would be a waste for the other devices, if this method works well and I can use it to use the best quality of the camera.
I could use a try{}catch() but it would be less than optimal.
Do you know any other way to return the quality of the camera?